# how to use optional url segment in Laravel?, but not at the end of the url

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing

I have this routes:

```
Route::prefix('/projects/{project}')->middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('/entel')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/search-by-code', [EntelController::class, 'searchByCode'])...
    ....
    ....
    });
   Route::prefix('/movistar')->group(function () {
   ....
   ....    
   });
   Route::prefix('/claro')->group(function () {
   ...
   ... 
   });    
});
```

EntelController.php :

```
class EntelController extends Controller
{
    public function searchByCode(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
    ....
```

I need two kinds of routes for the "entel" route (this is one of our clients)

**/projects/1/entel/search-by-code** and **/dev/projects/1/entel/seach-by-code**

These two routes should target the same controller and do the same, except that it should detect the url and do some stuff in the database, I am trying to do this:

```
Route::prefix('/{dev?}/projects/{project}')->middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
  Route::prefix('/entel')->group(function () {
     Route::post('/search-by-code', [EntelController::class, 'searchByCode'])...
     ....
     ....
  });
});

Route::prefix('/projects/{project}')->middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
        
  Route::prefix('/movistar')->group(function () {
   ....
   ....    
  });
  Route::prefix('/movistar')->group(function () {
    ...
    ... 
  });    
});
```

And I get this error:

> "message":
> "App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\EntelController::searchByCode():
> Argument #2 ($project) must be of type App\Models\Project, string
> given

And when I do this:

```
Route::prefix('/dev/projects/{project}')
```

it works, but if **dev** is removed from the url the route fails because **dev** is not optional, what can I do? thanks

Comment: Optional URL parameters cannot go first; if you have something like `/{optional?}/{required}`, and you navigate to `/example`, the code doesn't know if `example` would be the optional or required one. You also should never have more than 1 optional parameter; `/{optional_one?}/{optional_two?}` runs into the same issue; `/example`, is that param 1 or 2?

Comment: thanks for the response, I need only one optional param

Comment: Then it needs to go _after_ `/{project}`, or not be optional, as I said in the first part of my comment  The note about multiple was just to reinforce how URL Parameters work.

Comment: If I put it after /{project}/{dev?} still is not working, only works if I put it at the end, but that is not required behaviour, and also, but I have seen some websites that uses for example this: /en/url and /url and can go the the url/content, I am not quite sure if they are using some htaccess file, but I am not using a server, I am using a lambda function

Comment: *"but not in the end of the url"* - Adding that to the question isn't going to change the fact that Laravel doesn't allow an optional URL Parameter anywhere but at the end of the URL  But if you want the answer to that question, it's "you can't do that with Laravel". My comment, and the linked duplicate show that. I have no idea how other websites handle that `/en/url` vs `/url` Routing, but `/{dev?}/projects/{project}` will _never_ work in Laravel. I don't have a solution for you; you're gonna have to refactor and try other approaches. Maybe a Query String `/projects/1?dev=true`?

Comment: I just wanted to try all the possible solutions before what I had in mind: add a subdomain, something like this: https://dev.url.com/projects/1/entel/search-by-code , I think it should be work :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252850/discussion-between-developerx-and-tim-lewis).